# Make Screenreader read messages on get-request

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I try to provide accessibility for users with screen readers in our online-application where error/warn/info messages are very important for the usage.

If I add messages via ajax, the aria-live and role="alert" attribute does good work. The messages are read first, then the other elements are read.

The second possibility is, that the messages get rendered on a page which is the result of a get-request. Then the messages are not read, they are page-content. So the user has to navigate to this messages, otherwise they won't get read.

Is there any possibility, that the messages are read on page load? I tried with JAWS 17 and IE 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an extra (hidden) region with role="alert" and update it using javascript. This way I get the best result, that the messages are read on POST (ajax) and GET requests.

Answer (score 3):

Send focus to the messages when they are updated by any action the user has taken. You can do this with a link, e.g. `<a href=#messages>` for `<div id=messages tabindex=0>`, or with your scripting. You may not need the tabindex if your messages are already in a focusable element.

Comment: Additionally, if you use tabindex=-1, you can programmatically set focus to the element e.g. <div id="errors" tabindex="-1"> and then set focus with a body onload: document.getElementById('errors').focus();

This will set the focus to the errors, but they will not otherwise appear in the focus order as they would with a tabindex=0

Comment: I think that setting the focus to other elements is not the best way to do it, because the focus should not be influenced, thats a non expected behaviour.

Comment: Moving focus is fine if it happens when the user has taken an action, such as clicking a link or a submit button. It's only a problem if you do it without user input.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting focus as described in another answer, it's a good idea to include an indication of errors in the page title as it's the first thing the users hear.

E.g. **Contact Us - 2 errors on page**